# How to parse/decode a multipart form-data using Python requests and requests-toolbelt

Tags: python, reactjs, api, aws-lambda, multipartform-data

I am trying to create a AWS Lambda function with a function URL. The function should accept a file (image) upload along with a few field like name, date and text.

I am sending the request from the frontend which is in REACTJS:

```
export async function postFormData(url, form) {
  const response = await axios({
    method: "post",
    url,
    data: form,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
  })

  return response.data
}
```

I am also using postman to test the API. However, I am unable to parse the fields in the lambda function, I keep getting the below error which I guess means the body is not formed correctly? But I am using postman to send it, so I am not sure what Im doing wrong

```
ImproperBodyPartContentException: content does not contain CR-LF-CR-LF
```

My AWS Lambda python3 code:

```
import json
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.multipart import decoder

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # get the request body and headers
    body = event['body']
    headers = event['headers']
    
    # decode the multipart/form-data request
    data = decoder.MultipartDecoder(body.encode(), headers['content-type'])

    # iterate over the parts of the request
    for part in data.parts:
        # check if the part is a file
        if part.headers[b'content-disposition'].startswith(b'form-data; name="file"; filename='):
            # get the filename and content type of the file
            filename = part.headers[b'content-disposition'].decode('utf-8').split('"')[3]
            content_type = part.headers[b'content-type'].decode('utf-8')
            # write the file content to disk or do something else with it
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(part.content)
        # if the part is not a file, print its content
        else:
            print(part.content.decode('utf-8'))

    # create the response
    response = {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps({'message': 'Request processed successfully'})
    }

    return response
```

I am only allowed to use requests and requests toolbelt for this, so if you can point me to a solution using only these two libraries, that will be appreciated.

In summary, I just want to create a python api using AWS Lambda that accepts a few string data like name, date and text and an image file. I want to then save the image file as .png in the /tmp dir.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # get the request body and headers
    headers = event['headers']
    # decode the multipart/form-data request
    postdata = base64.b64decode(event['body'])

    request = {} # Save request here
    
    for part in decoder.MultipartDecoder(postdata, headers['content-type']).parts:

        decoded_header = part.headers[b'Content-Disposition'].decode('utf-8')
        key = get_key(decoded_header)
        request[key] = part.content

    print(request) # This is the request




def get_key(form_data):
    # 'form-data; name="birth_date"', 'content': b'2012-123'
    key = form_data.split(";")[1].split("=")[1].replace('"', '')

    print(key)

    return key
```